# Quantization Aware Training issue in tensorflow 2.6 . AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'dtype'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, quantization-aware-training

I am training a U2Net model and want to use quantization aware training to reduce the size of the model. According to the official Docs regarding this, We need to import the library of tensorflow_model_optimization and use the quantize model function.

Issue - When i am using this, I am getting AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'dtype'
This is my model declaration code-

```
quantize_model = tfmot.quantization.keras.quantize_model

net_input = Input(shape=(256,256,3))

model_output = U2NET(net_input)

model = Model(inputs = net_input, outputs = model_output)

qa_model = quantize_model(model)
lr = 1e-3

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = lr)

bce = BinaryCrossentropy()

qa_model.compile(optimizer = opt, loss = loss, metrics = None)
```

U2net function is the model declaration part.I am able to get the normal model.summary().I am trying to train the model of google colab gpu. Without QAT the model is training fine.

Please help

Comment: Hi! Could you please attach the same as a Colab Gist?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the same issue